# Edit and delete data by id with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem with edit and delete data in CodeIgniter.
I've tried some optional but it wasn't work. can somebody help me?

here I attached controller and model.

#### View

data bahan baku

```
kode_bahan_baku = kbb
nama_bahan_baku = hps

edit bahan baku = edit_dbb
delete bahan baku = delete_dbb
```

#### Model:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Model_data extends CI_Model{

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

}

// Data Bahan Baku
public function set_dbb(){

    $data = array(

        'bb_code' => $this->input->post('kbb'),
        'bb_price' => $this->input->post('hps')
    );
    return $this->db->insert('data_bahan_baku',$data);
}

public function get_dbb(){

    $query = "select * from data_bahan_baku";
    $sql = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result = $sql->result();
} 

public function edit_dbb(){     

    $data = array(
            'bb_code' => $this->input->post('kbb'),
            'bb_price' => $this->input->post('hps')
        );

    $this->db->where('kbb',$id);
    $edit = $this->db->update('data_bahan_baku',$data);
    return $edit;
}   

public function delete_dbb($id){

$data = array(

    'bb_code' => $this->input->post('kbb'),

    'bb_price' => $this->input->post('hps')

);
    $this->db->where('kbb',$id);
    return $this->db->delete('data_bahan_baku');
}
```

#### Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Control_data extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("model_data");
}       

// Entry Data

/*Input Data Bahan Baku*/
public function data_bahan_baku(){

    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Data Bahan Baku";

    $data['result'] = $this->model_data->get_dbb();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kbb','Kode Bahan Baku','required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hps','Harga Per Satuan','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $this->load->view('data/data_bahan_baku',$data);

    }else{

        $this->model_data->set_dbb();
        $this->load->view('data/data_bahan_baku',$data);
    }

}

/*Edit Data Bahan Baku*/
public function edit_data_bahan_baku($id){
    $this->model_data->edit_dbb($id);
}

/*Delete Data Bahan Baku*/
public function delete_data_bahan_baku($id){

    $this->model_data->delete_dbb($id);
    redirect('control_data/data_bahan_baku');

}
```

Comment: Are you getting `$id` in `delete_data_bahan_baku`  and `edit_data_bahan_baku` functions?

Comment: i've added $id on those function

Comment: Try to echo `$id` in your edit and delete **Controller** methods to make sure there is value for the same. And aslo In the **Model** `edit_dbb()` you are not having any parameter. It should be `edit_dbb($id)`